# Склонение по числительным JS

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывести текущее время не проблема. Как вывести текущее время на JS с учётом склонения в зависимости от чисел?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function declOfNum(number, titles) {  
    cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];  
    return titles[ (number%100>4 && number%100<20)? 2 : cases[(number%10<5)?number%10:5] ];  
}
alert ( declOfNum(2 , ['час', 'часа', 'часов']) );
```

Comment: Спасибо, через 8 минут отмечу. Просто ради интереса как тоже самое сделать, если число отрицательно или с плавающей точкой?