# Как сделать склонения времени в javascript?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать склонения времени в javascript?

```
function updateSummary() {
$('#completion-time').text((completion_time <= 0 ? "Invalid" : completion_time <= 24 ? completion_time + " Часов" : Math.ceil(completion_time / 24) + " Дней"));
```

Как изменить функцию так, чтобы время отображалось с падежами? Чтобы было один час, два часа, пять часов. С днями тоже самое

Comment: Уже неоднократно поднимался вопрос. [Воспользуйтесь поиском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/975919/443746 нашел ответ. Как это решение адаптировать под мой код?